# How can I capture word by Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to capture the array key from a string.

Here are my words: `message[0][generic][0][elements][0][default_action][url]...`

I want to capture the array keys after `message[0][generic][0][elements][0]`, and the expected results are `default_action` and `url` etc.

I have tried following patterns but not work.

1. `message\[0\]\[generic\]\[0\]\[elements\]\[0\](?=\[(\w+)\])`: it captures `default_action` only;
2. `\[(\w+)\]`: it captures all array keys, but includes `0`, `generic`, `elements`...

Is there any regex pattern for JavaScript that make the result array inverse, like `[url, default_action]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract any number of keys and reverse the order of the elements in resulting array:

```js
str = "message[0][generic][0][elements][0][default_action][url]";
res = str.match(/\[([^\d\]]+)\](?=\[[^\d\]]*\]|$)/g)
  .map(function(s) { return s.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "") })
  .reverse();
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace unwanted part of a string,and then get all other keys.

```js
var string = 'message[0][generic][0][elements][0][default_action][url][imthird]';

var regexp = /message\[0\]\[generic\]\[0\]\[elements\]\[0\]/

var answer = string.replace(regexp,'').match(/[^\[\]]+/g)

console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.prototype.split()` and `Array.prototype.slice()` functions:

```js
var s = 'message[0][generic][0][elements][0][default_action][url]...',
    result = s.split(/\]\[|[\[\]]/g).slice(-3,-1);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It will fail if there is more than 2 addational keys.It matches last two keys only

Comment: @JanCiołek, the OP didn't say that there could be *more than 2 addational keys*

Comment: I think he did,maybe not specifically but still.<br>`message[0][generic][0][elements][0][default_action][url]...` these dots mean something,but i can be wrong,anyway good job!